# jScrollPane stops scrolling when mouse is over iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, scroll, jscrollpane

I'm using the jScrollPane plugin and it's working great. However, as you scroll a DIV, the scrolling process will get interrupted if your mouse cursor passes over an iFrame. This is not the case with just a regular scroll bar (without the jScrollPane plugin).

Does anyone have any insight into this?